# Is class aggregation relationship in Java only achieved through instance objects?

Tags: java, oop, associations, aggregation

if class A calls a static method from class B, does that still qualify as 'aggregation' relationship?
for that matter, is class association also only achieved by calling class objects or can calling static a method qualify as association relationship?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, association, along with its two special forms, aggregation and composition, are all defined in terms of interaction among object instances:

> *Association* defines a relationship between classes of objects that allows one object instance to cause another to perform an action on its behalf. [[Wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_(object-oriented_programming))

The only relationship *not* defined in terms of instances is *dependency*: it is established, for example, by receiving an instance as a parameter, or calling any method, static or not.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. so does that mean if class A simply makes a string variable String x = "chair"; class A is now aggregating class String?

Comment: @NewLearner If `x` is a member of the class (depending on a language it may be called a field, a property, or a member variable) then it's an aggregation (HAS-A). If it's a local variable, then it's simply a dependency.